# Trouble with running JSFUnit 2.0Beta1 & Jetty

Tags: jsfunit

I am trying to integrate JSFUnit 2.0.0 "Getting Started" Example on Jetty in maven environment.

Source available in Below URL:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JSFUnit200GettingStartedExample

I am able to execute this sample on JBossAs6, but facing problems on Jetty 7(i.e mvn -Pjetty-embedded test)

Errors I am Getting:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.515 sec <<< FAILURE!
org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest.createDeployment()
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:166)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generateDeployment(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:100)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generate(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:170)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:303)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$300(Arquillian.java:45)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:162)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve an artifact
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAsFiles(MavenBuilderImpl.java:324)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAsFiles(MavenBuilderImpl.java:293)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl$MavenArtifactsBuilderImpl.resolveAsFiles(MavenBuilderImpl.java:712)
    at org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest.prepareForJetty(HelloJSFTest.java:76)
    at org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest.createDeployment(HelloJSFTest.java:66)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.4-b03 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:253)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:283)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:315)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(MavenRepositorySystem.java:176)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAsFiles(MavenBuilderImpl.java:316)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.4-b03 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:930)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:925)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:681)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:675)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:420)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:411)
    ... 70 more

org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:204)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.afterClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:192)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:303)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$300(Arquillian.java:45)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

Is there any deprecated URL to access this jars?
Or any solution to over come this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Paste into maven's settings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
                    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
                    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>htmlunit</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <id>HtmlUnitSnapshots</id>
                    <name>HtmlUnit Snapshots</name>
                    <url>http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/m2-repo-snapshots</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <id>java.net</id>
                    <name>java.net</name>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```